# OpenGL - Render a sphere with fixed pixel radius

Tags: opengl, geometry, pixel, transformation

I am currently using glutsolidsphere() to render a sphere. Of course, after scaling, the sphere appears to be an ellipsoid. 
  So is there any way to render a sphere with fixed pixel radius ? I just want to draw a sphere in a certain place (x,y,z) with a certain radius in pixels (eg, r = 10 pixels) and make it sure that its shape will not be affected by modeling transformation.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your code is needed to properly answer the question. Right now, we can only guess at what the right answer might be.

Answer (score 1):

Transformation such as Rotation, Translation, and Scaling should not affect the way a sphere looks. Remember to scale correctly on all 3 axis by the same value. Or you can just multiply vertices by a constant scalar and that should scale the sphere without distorting it. If you still see distortion, it might be because of your camera (high FOV tends to distort near the edges) or a wrong aspect-ratio (re-sizing an openGL window does not preserve aspect-ratio).

Answer (score 0):

When you scale, you can scale in x, y, and z. If you scale with the same value in each dimension, it will stay a sphere.

If you want to apply a scaling that always gives the same size of the sphere, as measured in pixels, then you have to make a scaling based on the viewport size definition. These are the arguments you gave to glViewport().

For example, when scaling 'x', use factor k/width (where width is taken from glViewport). Choose constant 'k' as you want, depending on the size of the sphere.

It is possible to use glGet() to request the data that was sent with glViewport(), but reading data from OpenGL should be avoided. In worst case, it will wait for the pipeline to flush. A better idea is to remember what was used for glViewport().

You do realize that glut is old and no longer recommended? And that glutsolidsphere is based on deprecated fixed function pipeline OpenGL?